# Value read from spreadsheet and doing a split is giving error in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, openpyxl

I have the below spread-sheet entry,

[image]

I use the openpyxl and use the below command to get the value of the cell and do a split and get individual elements from the row [and only for column 2,3,4]. FOr certain row the elements are single and certain rows there are multiple elements.

```
 le_tmp = (sheet.cell(row=n+1, column=3).value).split(",")
```

But when it comes to the row 12,column 2 [i.e. the value is 32], i get the below error

> AttributeError: 'long' object has no attribute 'split'

Is it because its a single element and I am doing a split ? But i am doing split with , right. Not sure why i am getting the above error. Can anyone help me on this?

THanks !

Answer (score 1):

split() is a str method. I.e - you can only call it on strings.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split

You shouldn't need to use split, as multi values will be covered in openpyxl. Suggest you have a read up here: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick clarification. Just tried adding str().split(",") and it worked. But when I split and add into an array it add 'u in front of the element like eg: u'john', u'32', u'64'. Any particular reason why it adds so ?

Comment: The "u" means that the string is unicode. It means that characters like the following can be represented as well, instead of just ascii - whÍ„ÁŒ. For what you are trying to do there shouldn't be any difference.